# Word to describe an attribute one would either love or hate

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

> He has an audacity that those who know him either adore or despise.  His audacity is ***_*____** .
>
> There's only two kinds of people: those who love olives and those who hate it. Olives have a ***_*____** flavor.

Comment: *[Shibbolethic](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/shibboleth)*?

Comment: All-or-nothing? Binary? Bipolar?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would say:

His audacity is polarising.

Olives are polarising when it comes to favour.

Comment: I can't go with this usage in OP's specific instance. There's not a single instance of *olives are polarising* in Google Books (nor with the American *polarizing*). There's not even one for the archetypal *Marmite is polarising*.

Answer (score 5):

Technically speaking, Dohn Joe's *polarising* "ought" to be the right word here - and you might just get away with it in OP's first example, but it seems a somewhat quirky usage to me.

But in practice people would probably use *divisive* in the first case, and some more roundabout expression for the second. If it weren't for the preceding sentence, I personally would go for...

> Olives have a ["love it or hate it"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22love%20it%20or%20hate%20it%22&oq=%22love%20it%20or%20hate%20it%22&aqs=chrome.0.57j60.1049&sugexp=chrome,mod=18&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) flavour. *(often written as **love-it-or-hate-it**)*.

Answer (score 0):

Marmitey. As referring to marmite of which has the slogan "you either love it or hate it. Its a colloquialism but it fits well.